# Saving and loading scikit-multilearn model

Tags: python, keras, scikit-multilearn

I cannot find a way to reliably save and load a `BinaryRelevance` model from the `scikit-multilearn` library. I am using the `Keras` wrapper to be able to use a custom classifier.

I have tried to pickle the model, but I get the error `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Keras.fit.<locals>.<lambda>'`. I have also tried to save the parameters obtained through `model.get_params()`, but setting these parameters to a new `BinaryRelevance` object through `model.set_params()` does not set attributes for the `BinaryRelevance` object (such as the `classifiers_` attribute), meaning that it can't be used as intended. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I have the same problem